# How to judge whether there is a specific child(.haschild('#test[att="test"]')) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="target">
<div id="test" att="test"></div>
</div>
```

`$('target').haschild('#test')` should be `true`

`$('target').haschild('#test[att="test"]')` should be `true`

`$('target').haschild('#no')` should be `false`

Only `$('target')` is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test a few ways, here is one:

```
if($("#target > #test").length){
   //true
} else {
   //false
}
```

If you play with jQuery plugins, you can actually use the syntax you use in your example:

```
$.fn.haschild = function(selector){
  return ($("> " + selector, this).length > 0);
}

$(function(){
  alert($('#target').haschild('#test')); // Alerts true
  alert($('#target').haschild('#test[att="test"]'));  // Alerts true
  alert($('#target').haschild('#no'));  // Alerts false
});
```

[**Here is a working example**](http://jsbin.com/emuxi)

Comment: @unknown I updated my answer to make a little jQuery plugin. It will do what you want.

Comment: No,I need to judge whether it's immediate children

Comment: Very strange,it doesn't work with `$('> img[src="folderopen.gif"],$scope)`

Comment: You are right, but it seems to be a jQuery bug. Its really weird!

Comment: I'll post it in another question.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('target').children('#test').length == 0
```

or

```
$('target > #test').length == 0
```

Comment: It doesn't work for this case:`.children('#test[att="test"]')`

Comment: you only need the ID, not the attribute test since all ids are unique

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an example found [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selector-that-matches-element-with-more-than-one-child) to suit this example, you can extend JQuery to have a new :haschild selector, as well as the method,

The you can use `$('#target:haschild(#test)')` as well as `.haschild('#test')`

```
$.fn.haschild = function(selector){
      function filterMethod(){
            if (selector) {
                  return $(this).children(selector).length >= 1;
            }
            return $(this).children().length >= 1;            
      }
      return this.filter(filterMethod);
}
$.expr[':'].haschild = function(objNode,intStackIndex,arrProperties,arrNodeStack){      
      var selector = arrProperties[3];
      if (selector) {
            return $(objNode).children(selector).length >= 1;
      }
      return $(objNode).children().length >= 1;
}
```