# Is there a work around for this jQuery bug?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
$('> img[src="folderopen.gif"]',$scope)
```

The above will fail,seems a bug of jQuery,is there a work around?

This issue is found here:

[How to judge whether there is a specific child(.haschild('#test[att="test"]')) with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062381/how-to-judge-whether-there-is-a-specific-child-haschildtestatttest-wi/2062390#2062390)

**EDiT**

I've just verified this will also fail:

```
$scope.children( 'img[src="folderopen.gif"]');
```

Comment: For those not believing this is a bug, please see this example on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/itufa/edit When you switch to "Output" you will see the problem.

Comment: What is $scope? Where are you defining it? Why are you using PHP syntax for the variable?

Comment: unknown, I've updated my answer with a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Tested, and Works:

Demo Online: http://jsbin.com/uyuri3

```
<p id="scope"> 
  <img src="foo.jpg" /> 
</p>
```

-- with --

```
$(function(){
  var scope = $("#scope");
  alert( $(scope).children("img[src$='foo.jpg']").attr("src") );
});
```

-- works with your original syntax too --

```
var img = $("> img[src$='foo.jpg']", scope);
```

---

#### An Interesting Bug

We know that our `src` value is `foo.jpg`, yet the following fails:

```
$("img[src='foo.jpg']");
```

So I was curious if jQuery's interpretation of the `src` would be equal to the string literal source I provided in the HTML:

```
$("img", scope).attr("src") === "foo.jpg"; // true
```

This makes the whole situation very strange. jQuery argues that the `src` value is **NOT** equal to "foo.jpg" when you pass it in as part of the selector, but it **IS** equal to the string literal when you compare from a call to `attr()`.

In the end, `$=` is necessary to get jQuery to agree that "foo.jpg" is equal to "foo.jpg". This certainly is a bug, but not an insurmountable one.

Comment: I've never seen `$=`,what does it mean?

Comment: It means the attribute "ends with" a particular value.

Comment: Apparently the exact value isn't understood to be the exact value by jQuery. Turns out it *is* a bug, but not an insurmountable one. If this helped, please consider accepting.

Comment: Yes,I'll accept your answer plus +1 vote.But I still don't understand why `$=` is necessary here.

Comment: unknown, it's very strange. I'm going to add a bit of further discussion to my answer. Keep watching :)

Comment: Yes. If it ends with `foo.jpg` (kungfoo.jpg, for example), it evaluates to true.

Comment: I hope this bug will disappear in next release of jQuery.

Comment: It is present in 1.4 due to be released today. I'll open a bug report tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You should just do:

```
$(scope).children("img[src='folderopen.gif']");
```

From that expression I assume you're doing some kind of tree like structure (like Windows Explorer). If so, I'd strongly urge you to instead use classes as markers rather than using attribute selectors, which are slow on most browsers. For example, with this CSS:

```
ul.tree li { background: url(folderclosed.gif); }
ul.tree li.open { background: url(folderopen.gif); }
```

you'd then do:

```
$(scope).children("li.open")...
```

which will be *much* faster.